# Display "no results found" if there is no matching search text input on the table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I saw this block of code from w3schools and it works perfectly fine. My only issue is that, if the inputted text is not present on the table, it doesn't display anything.

Here's the script code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#searchBar').on('keyup', function() {
      var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
      $('#tableData tr').filter(function() {
           $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
      });
   });
});
```

Here's the link to the w3schools article that I am talking about:
https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_filters.asp

I'd like to display a text saying "No results found" if there are no search results.

Answer (score 0):

Here my solution for your problem I think this is the optimal solution for your problem.

Here the HTML which I get from the link you provided of w3school I added here a new row in HTML , little style and some conditional line in the JS code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    .no-data {
    display: none;
    text-align: center;
}
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Filterable Table</h2>
  <p>Type something in the input field to search the table for first names, last names or emails:</p>  
  <input class="form-control" id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search..">
  <br>
  <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="myTable">
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td>mary@mail.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@greatstuff.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Anja</td>
        <td>Ravendale</td>
        <td>a_r@test.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="no-data">
        <td colspan="4">No data</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  
  <p>Note that we start the search in tbody, to prevent filtering the table headers.</p>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    let check = true;
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#myTable tr").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
      if($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1){ 
        check = false;
        $('.no-data').hide();
      }
    });
    if(check){
        $('.no-data').show();
    }
  });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

the new row I added in HTML for showing "No data" is here:

```html
<tr class="no-data">
        <td colspan="4">No data</td>
    </tr>
```

style for the new row

```css
.no-data {
    display: none;
    text-align: center;
}
```

I added a some new conditional line in JS and after adding those the JS code is :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    let check = true;
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#myTable tr").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
      if($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1){ 
        check = false;
        $('.no-data').hide();
      }
    });
    if(check){
        $('.no-data').show();
    }
  });
});
```

Hope your problem is solved have a nice day .